# Youtube api upload video and set paid product placement field

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to upload a video on Youtube through their api but I can't find the field I need to set to inform youtube that the video has [paid product placements](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/154235#notify)
Here is my code:

```
Youtube.videos.insert({
            resource: {
                // Video title and description
                snippet: {
                    title: "Testing YoutTube API NodeJS module",
                    description: "Test video upload via YouTube API",
                    tags: ["music"],
                    defaultLanguage: "en"
                },
                // I don't want to spam my subscribers
                status: {
                    privacyStatus: "private"
                }
            }
            // This is for the callback function
            , part: "snippet,status"

            // Create the readable stream to upload the video
            , media: {
                body: fs.createReadStream(video_path)
            }
        }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Done.");
            }
        });
```

You can find a description of all the fields you can set when you upload a video [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos).

Answer (score 0):

There is no product placement property for video resources in the API yet. If you check the [video properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource-representation) there is no mention of it.